# Где лучше развернуть админку?

Tags: админка

Здравствуйте.

появилась необходимость написание админки для сайта.

посоветуйте где ее лучше разместить, я остановился на следующих вариантах:

1. вынести на поддомен, например dashboard.site.com
2. в отдельную папку, например: site.com/dashboard

основной критерий это же конечно безопасность.

Comment: безопасность подразумевает в том числе и https. вы готовы включать в сертификат еще и поддомен для админки (что обычно дороже) ? И если приложение взломают то доступ к БД наверняка получат, так что смогут сделать все что угодно и без админки

Comment: зачем админке https?

Comment: @verstala чтобы учётные данные не передавать в незашифрованном виде, открытыми любому снифферу на промежуточном узле.

Comment: @verstala Ну админ же будет вводить свой пароль, если не будет https то его просто перехватят где нибудь в сети. И через несколько лет браузеры вообще откажутся открывать не https сайты, к этому уже все готовятся ...

Answer (score 2):

[Как считают разработчики Sandstorm](https://docs.sandstorm.io/en/latest/administering/wildcard/#why-cant-sandstorm-map-every-app-under-one-domain-like-examplecomapp-name)...

#### ...отдельный поддомен безопаснее.

Они мотивируют это тем, как работает *Same Origin Policy*: она считает идентичность источников по набору [протокол, домен, порт] (но не путь!) и для страниц из одного источника существенно ослабляет ограничения на взаимодействие. По этой причине одно из требований к установке Sandstorm (пожалуй, самое неприятное) — наличие домена с SSL-сертификатом с wildcard (звёздочкой, на множество поддоменов сразу). (Вам это, впрочем, не потребуется.)

У разных доменов могут быть совершенно независимые cookies и localstorage (особенно актуально для моднявых SPA). Вы ведь явно где-то захотите запоминать идентификатор сессии. А если на основном сайте найдётся какая-нибудь XSS-уязвимость, в результате которой можно получить доступные для JS куки и/или содержимое localstorage какого-нибудь пользователя, есть риск утечки сессии админки или чего-нибудь такого же, не менее ценного. Нехорошо.

---

Но это не линия фронта. Эта разница сыграет роль только в том случае, если вы накосячите в ряде других мест. Например: оставите довольно внушительную дыру на основном сайте, не будете использовать `HttpOnly` для важных cookies (чтобы доступ из JS к ним был перекрыт) и плотный *Content-Security-Policy*.

Для Sandstorm требования гораздо выше чем для большинства веб-приложений по той причине, что они запускают код от сторонних разработчиков в рамках одной платформы. Они не знают заранее, какой код будет размещён в их "зёрнышках", насколько он безопасен. Поэтому они применяют все меры по изоляции приложений, до которых только могут дотянуться.